# what are the benefits of angular2 over standard firebase integration?

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire, angularfire2

I'm getting into **angular** and **ionic** hybrid app development and am looking to use a realtime firebase backend.

I've heard a lot about **angular fire2** but no ones really outlined why you should or shouldn't use it as it seems like just another thing to learn. Also as my main goal is hybrid app development with **ionic2** when you think they could be more compatible?

thanks!

Comment: Recommendations whether or which technology to use are off-topic on Stack Overflow. That said: AngularFire2 is made by the Angular2 and Firebase teams, so probably contains a lot of what they consider the best practice to integrate the two products. Plus: it's open source, so even if you don't use it, it should make a great case-study of how you can integrate the two.

Comment: ok fair enough, just thought i should ask saw lots of explanations of how to use it just none about why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of all it is about rxjs (Observable)

> AngularFire2 synchronizes data as objects using the
>   FirebaseObjectObservable. The FirebaseObjectObservable is not created
>   by itself, but through the AngularFire.database service.

Here you can read more about observables and the main concept using them in angular2 [Angular 2 Observable Data Services](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-observable-data-services)

The main idea of angular2 with firebase is as mantion:

- Observable based - Use the power of rxjs, Angular 2, and Firebase.
- Realtime bindings - Synchronize database collections as objects or
  lists.

Check [Angular2Fire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2)